# Ripple effect isn't fire properly onClick

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm trying to use this lib https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect. I tried the sample and everything works fines but when I try to use this with more views inside the RippleView like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ripple="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drive_layoutT"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <com.andexert.library.RippleView
        android:id="@+id/rippleView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ripple:rv_color="#797979">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/drive_layout"
            android:layout_height="72dp"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/drive_icon"
                android:layout_width="44dp"
                android:layout_height="44dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:padding="4dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">


                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="71dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="14dp">


                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/drive_menu_btn"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:paddingRight="10dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/button_overflow_menu"
                        android:layout_marginRight="2dp" />


                    <View
                        android:layout_width="22dp"
                        android:layout_height="22dp"
                        android:id="@+id/drive_badge"
                        android:padding="8dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/circle"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/drive_menu_btn"
                        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/drive_menu_btn" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:id="@+id/drive_name"
                        android:textColor="@color/grey_list_item_title"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/drive_menu_btn"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/drive_spinner"
                        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/drive_spinner" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:id="@+id/drive_details"
                        android:textColor="@color/grey_list_item_details"
                        android:textSize="10sp"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/drive_name"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/drive_badge"
                        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/drive_badge" />

                    <ProgressBar
                        style="@style/CustomProgressBar"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="2dp"
                        android:id="@+id/drive_progress_bar"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/drive_details"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                        android:indeterminate="false" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="9"
                        android:id="@+id/drive_badge_text"
                        android:layout_marginRight="6.5dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/drive_badge"
                        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/drive_badge" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="+"
                        android:id="@+id/drive_badge_plus"
                        android:textSize="7sp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/drive_badge"
                        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/drive_badge" />

                    <ProgressBar
                        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:id="@+id/drive_spinner"
                        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/drive_details"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/drive_badge"
                        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/drive_badge"
                        android:indeterminate="false"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/drive_divider"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0.8dp"
                    android:background="@color/grey_divider"
                    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </com.andexert.library.RippleView>



</LinearLayout>
```

The ripple effect doesn't fire onClick, if I make a long press click I can see that the ripple effect happens. So this leads to a conclusion which is that this delay is caused because the RippleView is loading all the views inside.

How can I fixe this? Or is there anything I'm getting wrong or any work around for this issue?

Comment: I think that the RippleView supports a single child underneath it, i.e. if you want multiple Views to have that effect you will have to create multiple RippleViews for each View.

Comment: I found this [lib](https://github.com/balysv/material-ripple) which worked well